# Asset pipeline ordering - override not working in production

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

I am having some differences in my production styling that I cannot diagnose.  Most elements are fine with a few minor exceptions.  My fonts are also affected by this in production.

In development the computed styling:

```
background-color: rgb(240, 242, 243);
html, body - rgb(240, 242, 243)                base.css:4
<s>body - #ffffff</s>                          bootstrap.css?body=1:303
```

and in production:

```
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
body - #ffffff                                  application-793...4c4e125c.css:9
<s>html, body - rgb(240, 242, 243)</s>          base.css:1
```

Asset settings in production:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

In development:

```
config.cache_classes = false
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

assets/application.css:

```
/*
*= require bootstrap
*= require font-awesome
*= require rails_bootstrap_forms
*= require fonts
*= require _activities
*= require _feedback
*= require _admin
*= require_self
*= require screen #base.css is imported here
*= require overrides
*/
```

my screen.scss:

```
@import "function";
@import url("fonts.css");
@import url("base.css");
@import url("header.css");
@import url("footer.css");
@import url("elements.css");
```

It looks like the precompiling ordering difference in production within the application-793...4c4e125c.css.  I thought bootstrap would compile first and base.css being called later would override the bootstrap default .  I've precompiled for production.  What am I missing about how the asset pipeline works?  I've read the rails documentation but cannot figure it out.

Comment: Can you try to use `@import "forms";` in scss instead of `@import url("fonts.css");` (for all imports), so it will be compiled in one file

Comment: Did the trick, thanks

Comment: Pavel, do you want to add your comment as answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
@import "forms";
```

in scss instead of (for all imports)

```
@import url("fonts.css");
```

so it will be compiled in one file.